# using repeater with where condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I am creating an online bookstore with .net and i have a problem with repeater. I am displaying all books with repeater without a problem but i want to display books which have more sale record than average. I have a 'BookSales' attribute in database which holds how many of a book have been saled. I take the average of this with this code in codebehid:

```
ETicaretEntities1 entity = new ETicaretEntities1();
        var salesAverage = entity.BookTable.Average(sales => sales.BookSales);            
        float satisOrtalama = float.Parse(salesAverage.ToString());
```

'satisOrtalama' holds the true average float without a problem.Here is my view side for displaying books:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <div class="templatemo_product_box">
                   <h1>EN ÇOK SATANLAR</h1>
                   <img src="<%#Eval("BookPicture") %>" alt="image" />
                     <div class="product_info">
                       <h2><%#Eval("BookName") %></h2>
                       <%#Eval("BookAuthor") %><br /><br />
                       <h3><%#Eval("BookPrice") %> TL</h3>
                    <div class="buy_now_button">
                        <a href="subpage.html" runat="server">Sepete Ekle</a>
                    </div>
                     </div> 
                 </div>    
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

For example if average is 1,6 than i want to display which book's 'BookSales' attribute 2 and more.

Comment: If your data source it is a DataSet, could you use the Filter property of the DataView to filter your data according to your calculated average?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use additional Linq expression before bind your data. And bind your repeater with new collection. I think it could be work:

```
var BookSalesMoreThan2=entity.BookTable.Where(p=>p.BookSales>(int)Math.Round(satisOrtalama,0));
```